# Read data from a Garmin GPSMap 62 device

Tags: javascript, garmin

I need to read data from a GPSMap 62 device using the device control Javascript library. Problem is, unlike older devices, this device stores its waypoints in separate .GPX files every day. The javascript library expects all tracks and waypoints to be in the current.gpx file, but the 62 stores them in e.g. Waypoints_06-MAY-14.gpx and so on each day.

Short of requiring users to manually upload the appropriate file, has anyone gotten the DeviceControl library to actually support the newer devices with separate GPX files?

As an added bonus, the Garmin Device Control library is deprecated, so no updates are forthcoming.

Some code

```
startReadFromGps: function(deviceNumber) {
     this.plugin.StartReadFromGps( deviceNumber ); //invokes the external plugin
},
```

Comment: cant you just rename the waypoints...gpx file to current.gpx? or just add the content to it ?

Comment: Yes, but the point is to let users have a nice seamless experience. I can't ask the user, who may only be semi-computer literate to start messing around with his GPS's files. ANd therein lies the problem.

Comment: @JuannStrauss cant the process of renaming be automated?

Comment: This seems like it would be easier in some other language? Is JavaScript a requirement?

Comment: Sadly not. The Garmin DeviceControl library is written in Javascript and works in conjunction with the Garmin Browser Plugin. If I were developing a desktop or windows store app, this wouldn't be such and issue, but the fact that it's a web application makes it absurdly difficult.

Comment: this is what i meant. the script could open the file and just rename it or may add the content to an other file... my ajax or some... does the garmin connects to the internet or should all be on the gamin self ?

Comment: Could you add some code to illustrate what you were doing with the older devices?

Comment: I guess a good deal would be to merge those files, then read data from them.

Comment: Because this is a web/browser based application, the local storage access is handled by a proprietary browser plugin developed by Garmin and is NOT open source. The only access you have to the file is via the ReadFromDevice() function which only takes filetype as an argument, not filepath.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked out plugin in version [`2.3-RC1`](http://developer.garmin.com/web/communicator-api-2.3-RC1/garmin/device/GarminDevicePlugin.js) (I do not know, which version do you use).

Indeed there is `startReadFromGps` method:

```
/** Initiates the read from the gps device conneted. Use finishReadFromGps and getGpsProgressXml to 
 * determine when the plugin is done with this operation. Also, use getGpsXml to extract the
 * actual data from the device. <br/>
 * <br/>
 * Minimum plugin version 2.0.0.4
 * 
 * @param deviceNumber {Number} assigned by the plugin, see getDevicesXml for 
 * assignment of that number.
 * @see #finishReadFromGps
 * @see #cancelReadFromGps
 * @see #getDevicesXml
 */
startReadFromGps: function(deviceNumber) {
     this.plugin.StartReadFromGps( deviceNumber );
},
```

So it uses `getGpsXml`. I assume that it uses specified filename that is read and method returns file's content. My first thought is to change the filename - it is possible with:

```
/** This the filename that wil contain the gps xml once the transfer is complete. Use with 
 * setWriteGpsXml to set what the file contents will be. Also, use startWriteToGps to 
 * actually make the write happen.
 * 
 * @private
 * @param filename {String} the actual filename that will end up on the device. Should only be the
 * name and not the extension. The plugin will append the extension portion to the file name--typically .gpx.
 * @see #setWriteGpsXml, #startWriteToGps, #startWriteFitnessData
 */
_setWriteFilename: function(filename) {
    this.plugin.FileName = filename;
},
```

But `_setWriteFilename` is private method. However called by

```
startWriteToGps: function(gpsXml, filename, deviceNumber)
```

and

```
startWriteFitnessData: function(tcdXml, deviceNumber, filename, dataTypeName)
```

Since now I will check if calling those methods with your specified `filename` will override filename value permanently and further calling of `startReadFromGps` will use new `filename`.

I cannot test it, I didn't use this library but you can give a shot.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to change file names to read, not write.

Comment: @JuannStrauss Sure - but it should change filename in general. I bet that if you set new filename using above methods, filename will be the same if you will read after that.

Comment: I understand. It makes sense. But it doesn't work. If I write data to test.gpx, it still reads from current.gpx.

Comment: @JuannStrauss What version do you use ?

Comment: @JuannStrauss What number ?

Comment: Plugin: 4.1.0. Javascript DeviceControl library: v1.10